# Mend(WhiteSource) Bolt not generating Vulnerability Report in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, whitesource-bolt

**Mend Bolt free version.**

I have added a Mend Bolt task in my Build pipeline. It generates the report for one of the build pipelines.
[image]

But for the 2nd Build pipeline, it shows following:
[image: Mend Bolt output]

The repo is a node.js project & there are packages being used.

What is the cause of this error & how to get the report?
Is it a limitation of the free version?

Comment: Or is it because I am using a new project for the second pipeline?
for the first, I am using Project A, for 2nd, I am using project B in Mend task.
I am not sure but that's how it should be right? 
Then there may be a limitations on this project count as well.

Comment: As I understand It is free for open source project so I assume it is one project repo., there for just write to Mend support and ask them. It is unclear the way Mend present the free product.

Comment: Did you try to isolate and run B alone?